# Is there any disadvantage of downloading all corpora in nltk?

Tags: python, nltk

Assuming server space is not a constraint, is it still advised to download selective corpora and not all ?

I am aware, it would add to the time of certain operations .e.g creation of virtualenv.

But will there be some performance difference of nltk if selective corpora are downloaded, or all are downloaded ?

Comment: I guess it ends up as a personal preference. Do you like `batteries included` and `full set collection` or do you like `each sold separately` more?

Comment: @Nathan's answer is entirely correct: There is no runtime or memory penalty to having unused resources in `nltk_data`. It should be added that if you simply dislike having to run the downloader again and again and again whenever you try something new, or risk overlooking something for a virtualenv, it's generally enough to **download the `"book"` collection (interactively or with `nltk.download("book")`).** Downloading `"all"` is overkill (though harmless).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is `no`

NLTK uses a class called `LazyCorpusLoader` for the corpora which are not loaded until needed. Therefore even if you import a corpus it is not loaded in memory right away.

for example, with the brown corpus:

```
>>> from nltk import corpus
>>> type(corpus.brown)
<class 'nltk.corpus.util.LazyCorpusLoader'>
```

## Memory usage

As for memory usage, the corpora wont be loaded until read. We can view this by using the `resource` module. Here is an example with the brown corpus:

```
>>> import resource
>>> from nltk import corpus
>>>
>>> # show memory used after importing corpus
...
>>> resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
77780
>>> # show memory usage after import ALL corpuses
...
>>> from nltk.corpus import *
>>> resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
77780
```

As you can see there is no change in memory usage. It will only increase after you load the corpus data into memory, in this example by calling `tagged_sents()`

```
>>> sents = corpus.brown.tagged_sents()
>>> resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
78276
```

## Space usage

NLTK by default downloads corpora data on unix like systems to `~/nltk_data/corpora`. upon writing this response, I should have the most up to date downloads for all corpora.

A quick check on size shows:

```
 $ du -sh ~/nltk_data/corpora/
 8.5G   ~/nltk_data/corpora/
```

I know you mentioned that server space is not a constraint, but due to the `LazyCorpusLoader`, you may be interested in taking it into account.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes any difference since the corpora are independent and you'll have to load each one separately to use it. You can download all of them if you wish.

And of course, there is the assumption that you're not going to make a *wildcard import* for all of them.